# testing analytics SDK based app without actually deploying it on App Store

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links, reward-system

1. I want to integrate `user reward referral` functionality in my app. To achieve the same with the help of `Firebase`, I generated a unique link (by formatting link parameter) with the help of `dynamic builder API`. This link is working fine (No error found in  Debug Dynamic Links doc). Now, I send this dynamic link to my friend, he is redirected to app store, he downloaded the app but current version of app present on app store, does not have the Firebase SDK integrated. I want to track events like successful installation through my unique dynamic link, then to reward referrer and referee with some amount . Will I able to track this? or is it necessary that my app being downloaded from app store should also have Firebase SDK integrated?
2. If it is necessary then in that scenario, how would i test that the analytics of events(install, first_open etc.) are working fine or not, without actually releasing my app on app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Firebase SDK must be integrated in order for the referral to be tracked.**

This is because the SDK is used to verify whether that user came from a Firebase link, without the SDK that user will simply look like a direct install, not a referral. You're best option is to have two test devices. Send the referral link from one device to the other, then tap the link on the device that received the link. After the tap, install the Firebase version on that same device from your computer and open it. (you might have to delete the app off of the referred app first if it was already installed). This should trigger a referral count.

I also recommend checking our [Branch](http://docs.branch.io) as they have a much more out of the box referral system with their deep links.

Answer (score 0):

As Clay says, the SDK is needed for tracking via Google Analytics. For the second point: first_open will trigger even if you install just on your test device locally.

You can use the GA [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) in the Firebase console to see the events come in live, which makes testing pretty straightforward!

Comment: As far as i know Firebase takes only 1-3 hours to show application's analytic behaviour but even after waiting for a day, My Firebase analytic console is blank on DebugView/StreamView.
Will it take more time?

Comment: I am able to see the analytics details on Xcode logs properly but not on Firebase console.

Comment: @ShradhaSharma : For Xcode, Open project , Project->Scheme->Edit Scheme, Popup will open , left side select "Run" , Right left select "Arguments" tab ,  see "Arguments passed on launch" -> click on "+" icon add `-FIRDebugEnabled` and then `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` and you are done.